# What does $\sin(\sin(x))$ mean?

Tags: trigonometry

What does an equation like $\sin(\sin(x))$ mean? I know it can be seen as a composite function $f(f(x))$, where $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Is there a way to simplify functions like this, and where will this be used? Thanks in advance.
P.S. I have looked at the graph of $f(x)=\sin(\sin(x))$ and compared it to the graph of $g(x)=\sin(x)$. They look pretty similar, but $f(x)=\sin(\sin(x))$ has a smaller amplitude

Comment: http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math/2005-04/msg03927.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In line with the link given in @Mathster's comment, we can look at the Fourier series of $\sin(\sin(x))$. If that is an unfamiliar term, what that means is basically the following equation holds:

$$\sin(\sin(x)) \approx 0.8801 \sin(x)+ 0.0391 \sin(3x) + 0.0005 \sin(5x).$$

(See the plot of the difference of the two functions [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.8801%20sin%28x%29%2b%200.0391%20sin%283x%29%20%2b%200.0005%20sin%285x%29%20-%20sin%28sin%28x%29%29).) The numbers in the expression given are rounded to four decimal places and we could add more terms of the form $\sin((2n+1)x)$, but their coefficients will get smaller and smaller. If you look at the graph given you'll see the error is less than $0.00003$.

Answer (score 8):

$\sin(\sin x))$ is not an equation.

There is no way to simplify it.

It will be used to test whether you have learned the Chain Rule, when you get to Calculus.

Comment: For OP: It's not an equation because it has no equals sign; it's an _expression_ or _formula_.

Answer (score 6):

Besides hydrodynamics and wave equations, it also shows up in frequency modulation applications, which is electrical engineering. It expands exactly using Bessel functions of the first kind

$$ \sin(\sin(x)) = J_1(1) \sin(x) + J_3(1) \sin(3x) + J_5(1) \sin(5x) + … $$

Go to the Wikipedia entry for [Frequency Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation) for more info

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful a lot when dealing with extensions of iterative functions to real or complex plane such as in case of collatz function:

$C\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{2}\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)+\frac{\left(3x+1\right)}{2}\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi\left(x-1\right)}{2}\right)$

and then $C(C(C(C...(x)))...)$